# Feature with multiple choice solutions in Logit

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, classification

I want to train a logit model, but I have a feature (exogenous variable) that has multiple possible categories  in one cell. The reason for that is that multiple answered (multiple-choice) were allowed to one question in a questionnaire.

Example: Variable 'Cuisine preferences'

Row 1 : Mexican, Italian, Asian
Row 2 : Mexican, Arab, American
Row 3 : International Fastfood, American
..........

I hot-one encoded, such that each listed outcome is a variable on it's own. I don't know whether that is the way to go, since I will lose a reference category.

What is the way to go in Python.

Answer (score 6):

A question where respondents can pick several non-mutually exclusive options can simply be treated as a series of multiple binary questions, because this is what this kind of question actually is.

In your case, your binary questions are: "Mexican food: Yes/No", "Italian food: Yes/No", "Arab food: Yes/No", etc.

Contrary to what you did, you should absolutely not treat your dataset as if "Mexican, Italian, Asian" was a single option, because you'll lose a lot of information, and the variable may end up with a cardinality so high that it could be essentially useless for your model – no matter if the goal of your model is predictive or explanatory.

So from your example, you should transform your dataset such as you'll have a table looking like that, where "1" is when they picked the option and "0" when they didn't pick it:

| id | Mexican | Italian | Asian | Arab | International fastfood | American |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| row 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| row 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

This solution not only makes your concern about the reference category beside the point, but it also gives you more flexibility for modeling (e.g. you can model interactions as you wish).

How to proceed to transform your dataset like that using Python is outside the scope of this website. However, you'll find resources about it on https://stackoverflow.com, for instance look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830169/how-to-split-comma-separated-text-into-columns-on-pandas-dataframe.

By the way, a problem with presenting this kind of question like you did is that it may be difficult to distinguish between respondents who actually answer for instance "*no, I don't like Italian food*" and respondents who did not answer (e.g. because they read the survey quickly and superficially, and did not see there was an "Italian food" option; or because they simply never tried this kind of food, so they can't really tell if they like it or not).

Unfortunately, there's no way around this problem once the data has been collected; this is something that should be dealt with at the design stage of the survey. You should check if the options appearing last in the list of choices presented to respondents tend to be chosen less often; it can be indicative of a problem relative to that.